# Spring Boot Actuator endpoints not showing data

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to scrape data from actuator/metrics using prometheus. I have read similar questions on stackoverflow but none of the answers worked for me. Anyway when I try `actuator/metrics` I get:`{"names":[]}` or for example if I do: `/info` I get `{}` . I also keep on getting `{"status":"DOWN"}` from `actuator/health` which is weird since the server is running fine. I have tried disabling spring security and the following configurations:

```
<Parameter name="management.endpoints.web.exposure.include" value="*"/>
    <Parameter name="management.endpoints.web.expose" value="*"/>
    <Parameter name="management.endpoints.web.exposure.include" value="metrics"/>
    <Parameter name="management.security.enabled" value="false"/>
    <Parameter name="management.endpoint.metrics.show-details" value="always"/>     
    <Parameter name="management.metrics.consul.enabled" value="false"/>
    <Parameter name="endpoints.actuator.enabled" value="true"/>
    <Parameter name="endpoints.metrics.enabled" value="true"/>
    <Parameter name="management.endpoints.beans.enabled" value="false"/>
    <Parameter name="management.endpoint.metrics.enabled" value="true"/>    
    <Parameter name="management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include" value="metrics"/>
```

My dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check if your spring boot app is using the same port of prometheus server. Maybe one is blockung the other

Comment: I don't have the prometheus server running.

Comment: If you have spring security, did you disabled csrf on security settings?

Comment: Yeah, I disabled everything. http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();

Comment: Try to change the valeu of the property management.endpoints.web.exposure.include from metrics to *

Comment: And see If data is returned

Comment: Have tried that also, didn't make a difference.